# Can I show attachments on a card in reverse order?

Tags: trello

I'd like to see the attachment that was added last at the top of my card in Trello. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The last uploaded attachment shows up at the top of the list. Older attachments are hidden under the "View all..." link. There's no option to reverse the order.